# Global assemby reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm new to C# and ASP.Net core.

I'm using ASP.Net core 1.1 and I have referenced a project, how can I make this referenced project globally visible to all controlles, so I don't have to type "using MyReference" in all controllers?

I tried adding it to my csproj file under `<Reference Include="MyReference" />` but it still wants me to add "using..." in the controller.

How can I make it globally?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do that.  You can do it for views (ie. .cshtml files) by including it in the _ViewImports.cshtml file like so:

```
 @using MyReference
```

But for .cs files I don't think there is any way to do that.  You will need to include the using at the top of each file.  If you are using Visual Studio, you can automate this by modifying the default template for your code so that when you start a new code file it's automatically in there since you made it part of the template.  If you are not using Visual Studio, many other editors have this same feature, so look into their docs on how to modify the code file template.